# Error when using barplot in R: Error in width/2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, bar-chart

I want to make bar charts in R.

```
# the data
> dput(CK)
structure(c(2L, 1L, 12L, 2L, 24L, 26L, 17L, 0L, 7L, 2L, 0L, 16L, 
43L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 5L), .Dim = c(6L, 3L), .Dimnames = structure(list(
c("BL 1", "BL 2", "IM", "ML", "MSL", "LAR"), c("nicht", "gering", 
"hoch")), .Names = c("", "")), class = "table")

> dput(AR)
structure(c(62L, 1L, 16L, 8L, 25L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 15L, 
0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 31L), .Dim = c(6L, 3L), .Dimnames = structure(list(
c("BL 1", "BL 2", "IM", "ML", "MSL", "LAR"), c("nicht", "gering", 
"hoch")), .Names = c("", "")), class = "table")

# the plots
barplot(t(CK), col=c("#66c2a5","#fc8d62", "#8da0cb"), space=0.04, font.axis=2, "CK")
barplot(t(AR), col=c("#66c2a5","#fc8d62", "#8da0cb"), space=0.04, font.axis=2, "AR")
```

The first plot works fine. The second plot throws the error:

`Error in width/2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(width) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`

What is causing the different behaviour in plots for pretty similar tables?

Answer (score 0):

First off, the error originates from the first `barplot` call. Since neither of the two `barplot` calls produces a figure, I am not entirely sure how your output plots are supposed to look like.

That aside, here is an alternative using `ggplot2`, where we can make use of `facet_wrap` to plot both the `CK` and `AR` data in one go.

```
library(tidyverse);
df <- bind_rows(
    list(
        CK = CK %>% as.data.frame.matrix() %>% rownames_to_column("x"),
        AR = AR %>% as.data.frame.matrix() %>% rownames_to_column("x")),
    .id = "id")
df %>%
    gather(key, value, -id, -x) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = id, y = value, fill = key)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    facet_wrap(~id, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

---

### Update

Or perhaps this is closer to what you're after?

```
df %>%
    gather(key, value, -id, -x) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = x, y = value, fill = key)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    facet_wrap(~id, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, how do I add a plot to a question?

Comment: Are you asking [how to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)? If so, please see the link.

Comment: @ke.re I've also updated my post with a different plot that might be closer to what you're after. Please take a look.

Comment: Thanks. I think the problem is when I use `table()` to create the barplot data. I switched to ggplot but I dislike the reshuffling of variable order that comes with it.

Comment: @ke.re It's fairly easy to re-arrange the order of variables by changing the order of the `factor` levels (there exist plenty of post around that topic here on SO). The `ggplot` syntax is definitely idiosyncratic but once you wrap your head around it, it's very elegant and straightforward IMO.